# gpx conversion tools in qgis keeps asking for GPSBabel

Tags: qgis, gpsbabel

I want to perform a simple task: show the waypoints of a GPX "track" as dots, not as a set of connected lines in QGIS ( *Conversion -> Waypoints from a track* ). I use files, not any particular USB connected device. Just GPX standard files. QGIS keeps asking for a "GPSBabel" module. Did I miss something? The same data is imported as a "track" without problem.

( I'm using the version 1.8 of qgis )